# How can I add rewrite rules like 'mysite.com/category-name.html' in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

How can I add rewrite rules like this in wordpress?

```
mysite.com/categoryname-postname.html
```

For example is easy to add url like this?

```
mysite.com/category/category_name

[category/(.+?)/?$] => index.php?category_name=$matches[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if the standard mechanism is good enough for you. In admin mode, go to Settings - Permalinks and select one that you like of define your own. Maybe the Optional section is for you.
2. To be more flexible, you can use a plugin, like http://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite/
3. To be totally flexible, you can directly edit the .htaccess file (use Google to learn how to write rules). Be careful, one false letter and the whole page may crash.